# Error while Installing mod_perl

Tags: perl, apache2, web-deployment, mod-perl, apxs2

I am getting an error as shown below while installing mod_perl.
I am using Ubuntu 12.04 , Apache2.2.22 , Perl 5.14. 
Please let me know How can i fix it

```
root@hafsal-sparksupport:~/mod_perl-2.0.7# perl Makefile.PL MP_APXS=/usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
Reading Makefile.PL args from @ARGV
   MP_APXS = /usr/local/apache2/bin/apxs
no conflicting prior mod_perl version found - good.
************* WARNING *************

  Your Perl is configured to link against libgdbm,
  but libgdbm.so was not found.
  You could just symlink it to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgdbm.so.3.0.0


************* WARNING *************
[  error] Unable to determine server version, aborting.
[  error] Invalid MP_APXS specified?
```

Answer (score 7):

Install the libgdm dev package:

```
aptitude install libgdbm-dev
```

Comment: Thank you for replying!!! Now i am getting.                            [  error] Unable to determine server version, aborting.
[  error] Invalid MP_APXS specified? . I couldn't find out any file with name Apxs in my system. I have installed apche2. Please let me know how can i install apxs?